# Family booking of 35-40 people on Indian Railways - is it possible?

Tags: india, bookings, family, indian-railways

We are planning to travel in a group of 35-40 people. Can I make a railway booking in bulk for all of them in one go (I'm already a registered member at IRCTC) ?

Answer (score 5):

IRCTC doesn't provide bulk booking services. 
Section "B. Services NOT Offered" mentions "Bulk Booking for families and groups" in the [terms and conditions page on irctc](https://www.services.irctc.co.in/cgi-bin/bv60.dll/IndianRailways/jsp5/termsConditions.jsp).

You can book the bulk ticket from the starting station of the journey. Check [this discussion](http://indiarailinfo.com/faq/post/what-is-bulk-block-or-group-booking-what-is-the-process-of-this-booking/527)

Comment: +1 To the OPs point no bulk booking is not possible in IRCTC